# RunTimeException can't be handle in catch block

Tags: java, exception

If I write RunTimeException in catch block then why it is not handled.

```
class main{
    public static void main(String cs[]){
        try{
            int a = 10/0;
        }
        catch(RunTimeException e){
            System.out.println("exception caught");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why there is an error if I write RunTimeException and not in case if I write the subclass of RunTimeException i.e ArithmaticException and super class Exception.

**error is**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
RunTimeException cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: Try to use a decent Java IDE and you will not have these kind of problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's RuntimeException and not RunTimeException. Java is a case-sensitive language.

Answer (score 2):

java is case sensitive language. Write `RuntimeException`  exception. Java uses **camel case** for method name and **pascal case** for class name. If you follow this rule you will get less exception. It would be easy to find out such exception if you use `IDE` such as `netbean/eclipse`. These IDE are free on internet to download